# Swift data missing in optional array

Tags: swift, oop

I'm totally confused about this. I append data to an optional array, but it's just gone. Here's the code to explain further:

Where the problem:

```
private func toObject(from data: GetOldDistrSrvMenuQuery.Data.GetOldDistrSrvMenu) -> GetOldDistrSrvMenu {
    let obj = GetOldDistrSrvMenu()
    obj.title = data.title
    obj.subtitle = data.subtitle
    obj.buttonText = data.buttonText
    obj.buttonShow = data.buttonShow ?? false
    obj.buttonUrl = data.buttonUrl
    
    if let items = data.items {
        for item in items {
            if let item = item {
                let aa = toDataObject(from: item)
                obj.items?.append(aa)
                
                print("Debug1: \(aa.name)") // data exist as expected
                print("Debug2: \(obj.items)") // nil in obj, why?
            }
        }
    }
    
    return obj
}
```

the toDataObject function:

```
private func toDataObject(from data: GetOldDistrSrvMenuQuery.Data.GetOldDistrSrvMenu.Item) -> GetOldDistrSrvMenuItem {
    let obj = GetOldDistrSrvMenuItem()
    obj.sourceUrl = data.sourceUrl
    obj.thumbnailUrl = data.thumbnailUrl
    obj.name = data.name
    
    return obj
}
```

GetOldDistrSrvMenu object:

```
class GetOldDistrSrvMenu: Object {
   @objc dynamic var _id: String = UUID().uuidString
   @objc dynamic var title: String?
   @objc dynamic var subtitle: String?
   @objc dynamic var buttonText: String?
   @objc dynamic var buttonShow: Bool = false
   @objc dynamic var buttonUrl: String?
   var items: [GetOldDistrSrvMenuItem]?

   override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
      return "_id"
   }
}

class GetOldDistrSrvMenuItem: Object {
   @objc dynamic var thumbnailUrl: String?
   @objc dynamic var name: String?
   @objc dynamic var sourceUrl: String?
}
```

Why is it missing in the obj array? I'm totally confused and don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Do you ever initialize the array?

Comment: yes, it's in the GetOldDistrSrvMenu object, in var items: []

Comment: You declared the array but you didn't initialize it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not initializing the array.

An optional array means it's a `nil`. Calling `append` (or any function) on a `nil` will not do anything.

**You have to initialize the array to an empty array at some point.**

`obj.items = []`

---

I highly recommend against using optional arrays, rather always default to a non-optional empty array.

There is very few situations where there's a difference between `[]` and `nil` array.

You can just do `var items: [GetOldDistrSrvMenuItem] = []`

Comment: totally my fault! All this time I think the optional array can be appended by item immediately. Thank you for your help.